# Redirect google bots, but show a 'Moved' page to visitors?

Tags: redirect

When moving a site to a new domain name, how can I show a 'This page has moved.' message to visitors and not automatically redirect, but at the same time tell Google and other bots that the sites have moved, to maintain SEO?

Or what is the best alternative? User agent cloaking isn't what I'm looking for.

What about the [canonical meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html)? Seems like each page would need it's own, and the content on those pages would need to be nearly the same, but I guess you could have a box pop up saying "we have moved" to the user or something. Is this a viable alternative, or are there any complications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide different content, depend ending on the user agent specified in the http request header. you can find an overview of googlebot user agents here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943. what language / framework are you using?

Comment: Isn't that called cloaking, and potentially very bad for SEO?